# Ruby on Rails : About how to display files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5

I can save the current file on database base, S3, but
Playback also confirmed in S3) When you look at files such as audio files & tapes, file files etc, it is not going well to output.
The file type is

```
  validates_attachment :file, content_type: { content_type: ['audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio', 'video/mp4', 'text/plain', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'application/pdf', "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }
```

It is the above file.
It was not possible to output these, now it is addicted.
Files that can not be output are audio files and text files. Video and image output is going well.

As for the preservation method,

```
<%= form_for @listing do |f| %>
        <div class="col-md-5">

          　　　　　　　<div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12 select">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <%= f.file_field :file, class: 'form-control' %>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="save" style="float:right;">
                      <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
                  </div>
        　</div>
  <% end %>
```

controller

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
　　new
   　　@listing = current_user.listings.build
  　end

  def create
    @listing = current_user.listings.build(listing_params)

    if @listing.save
      redirect_to listing_path(@listing), notice: "投稿を保存しました"
    else
      redirect_to new_listing_path, notice: "投稿を保存ができませんでした"
    end
  end

private
  def listing_params
    params.require(:listing).permit(:file)
  end
　def set_listing
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

gem,
gem 'paperclip', "~> 5.0.0.beta 1"
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'
I am trying.

And now the audio file is output as shown below.

[image]

And the code of show's view is written as follows.

```
<% if @listing.file_content_type == 'video/mp4' then %>
              <%= video_tag @listing.file, :controls => true, width: "640", height: "360" %>
<% elsif @listing.file_content_type == "image/jpg" || "image/jpeg" || "image/png" || "image/gif" then %>
              <%= image_tag @listing.file, :width => 640, :height => 340 %>
<% elsif ['audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3'].include?(@listing.file_content_type) then %>
              <%= audio_tag @listing.file, :controls => true %>
 <% else %>
              <%= image_tag @listing.file %>
 <% end %>
```

It is a situation that I do not know how to do it in accordance with the file format, respectively.
Where should I edit?
please tell me.

Comment: Unrelated to question: you can use Regex to simplify this condition: `['audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3'].include?(@listing.file_content_type)`. Match `@listing.file_content_type` to `/^audio\/.+/i`.

Comment: can you `puts @listing.file_content_type.inspect` so you know what it is for this audio file?

Comment: thank you comment! It is mp3 file.